# How to scan QR code to obtain records in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, odoo-8, odoo

As you may know, in Odoo *Warehouse* module, there is a barcode scanner, if you go to *Warehouse > Operations > All Operations* and you click on any of the buttons with the barcode picture.

This opens a JavaScript interface where you select any picking and then, you can start scanning EAN13 of products with a barcode scanner. The quantities of the moves of the picking increment as barcode scanner reads a new EAN13.

It seems that the barcode scanner starts pressing keys of the keyboard magically and the following JS code of *widgets.js* file (in *stock* module) gets the resultant string.

```
module.BarcodeScanner = instance.web.Class.extend({
    connect: function(callback){
        var code = "";
        var timeStamp = 0;
        var timeout = null;
        this.handler = function(e){
            if(e.which === 13){ //ignore returns
                return;
            }
            if(timeStamp + 50 < new Date().getTime()){
                code = "";
            }
            timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            code += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                if(code.length >= 3){
                    callback(code);
                }
                code = "";
            },100);
        };
        $('body').on('keypress', this.handler);
    },
    disconnect: function(){
        $('body').off('keypress', this.handler);
    },
});
```

The resultant string is supposed to be an EAN13, so Odoo looks for a product in the picking which matches that EAN13, and increments its quantity line.

This is working well, but my question is: can I emulate this behaviour but reading a QR code with a mobile phone instead of reading a barcode with a barcode scanner?

So what I want is to take the mobile phone, open Odoo, go into this JS interface, and read QR codes which sent the necessary info to increment the quantities of the picking lines.

This is very abstract for me, because I think the mobile camera must be used to read the QR code.

Is it possible to manage the purpose I am looking for (I do not want to program a mobile app)?